# Is it more efficient to filter rows in each union table select or filter only once on the parent select

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm trying to understand the performance logic between the following two stored procedures. Let's say I have a stored procedure that counts rows from three different tables based on a variable called @user. Is it better to filter the output on each table select or to filter only once on the "parent" select.

Stored Procedure 1

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProcedure1]   
@user NVARCHAR(150),
@postCount int out

AS 
   BEGIN
   SELECT @postCount = COUNT(unionPostCount.IDpost)
   FROM (
       SELECT IDpost FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.IDuser = @user        
       UNION ALL SELECT IDpost FROM Table2 WHERE Table2.IDuser = @user
       UNION ALL SELECT IDpost Table3 WHERE Table3.IDuser = @user
     ) 
   AS unionPostCount 
END
```

Stored Procedure 2

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProcedure2]   
@user NVARCHAR(150),
@postCount int out

AS 
   BEGIN
   SELECT @postCount = COUNT(unionPostCount.IDpost)
   FROM (
       SELECT IDpost FROM Table1        
       UNION ALL SELECT IDpost FROM Table2 
       UNION ALL SELECT IDpost Table3
     ) 
   AS unionPostCount WHERE unionPostCount.IDuser = @user 
END
```

I have the feeling that with very huge tables Procedure 2 is slower because it has to select all rows from three tables and then filter them but I might be wrong. Which of the two procedures is faster in performance? All help is well apprecated.

Comment: Do you have indexes on your IDuser  field?

Comment: What does "I have the feeling" mean? Just measure it :-) To your question: I'd assume, that the biggest performance deal would be an index on IDUser. In this case any count should be rocket fast... And one more point (speaking about performance): I'd never use a SP for this, rather an UDF.

Comment: Safe coding wise - the first should be the way to go. However, in this case, as there are supporting indexes, the optimizer will probably choose to optimize the second query, and to "rewrite" it to run as the first.  This case is very much like when querying from views, and the optimizer will apply the filter to each table separately if there are supporting indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed the answer as indeed Viktor was right. The plans are identical.

I still believe that 3 count operations should be faster depending on the size of the data retrieved, thought the most time spent is in finding the rows in all solutions. So I guess all solutions are close in terms of performans.

Comment: You forgot, that inner optimizer don't count unions individually. Both plans are equal. For example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f0aa/1 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f0aa/2

Comment: Actually the plans are not equal. Put also the count in your query and you will see how the plan changes.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f0aa/9 and http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f0aa/8 Don't see any difference

Comment: Yeah .. I see on fiddle .. what can I say, I can show you 2 different plans on my machines, both 2008/2014. Both plans differ from what fiddle shows.

Comment: It's interesting Can you share printscreens both queries and plans?

Comment: Sure, give me an email address pls. There is no point in continuing the discussion here.

Comment: You were right, I was comparing slightly different queries.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the'll have the same execution plan. Just be sure to have an index on IDuser for all tables involved.
For a faster solution count each select separately and add results.

Answer (score 2):

Inner optimizer don't count unions individually. 
Both plans are equal. 
For example [first SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f0aa/1) and [second SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f0aa/2)